# How to access adapter delete button into activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and adapter. Now in that adapter, I'm inflating one row. In that row, there are one delete button and one progressbar. So what I'm doing is when user clicks on delete button, I make invisible that delete button, and make visible small progress bar in place of delete button from **Adapter** class. And also I'm sending position via listener to that attached activity, from that I'm calling AsyncTask.

**Now the problem is**:

When I got to know via AsyncTask that item is deleted, I again want to make visible delete button and to make invisible progressbar. But this time - from Activity (not from adapter), because I want to do something in activity when I get to know that item is deleted. So I can't implement AsyncTask in adapter.

code:

Adapter

```
  delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        listener.onClicked(getAdapterPosition(), eventList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getEventId());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Activity (in activity I want to visible/invisible adapter row button and p.bar:

```
 @Override
    public void onDeleteDataReceived(Boolean status, int position) {
        stopShimmerLayout();
        if (status) {
            try {
                eventsList.remove(position);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                showToast(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            showToast(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
```

See the video for better understanding: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13ZAtnyfGbi2X4JjUTmJsIDy-gt5y51Gr

Comment: Create a function in adapter and call it from activity. for example mAdapter.yourFunction();

Comment: @Tara But how will I access delete and p.bar. it is inside view holder

Comment: through position you have position parameter in ur activity

Comment: @Tara I'm asking that we're accessing holder.delete in bindviewholder like that how will I access delete and p.bar in that function?. NOTE: I created function in adapter not in bindviewholder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457406/how-to-update-refresh-specific-item-in-recyclerview here is the idea if you don't understand let me know i will create a sample

Comment: @Tara Do you think I should make MyViewHolder global and access holder value from bindviewholder ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214023/discussion-between-tara-and-shefali-singh).

Comment: @Tara Okay, commented

Comment: so what I understood you want to delete an item from the list once you get the response from server?

Comment: @Gautam What is my problem is: Suppose I clicked delete button for first 5 items one by one
immediately within a sec. and suddenly I started scrolling recyclerview up and down very fast in that case, it is crashing and also while scrolling time that progressbar should not show in any random items.
like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493958/why-does-the-input-value-in-edittext-swaps-its-position-while-scrolling-in-a-rec/43112630#43112630

Comment: @ShefaliSingh to fix the crash you need to check the error in logcat. And regarding your second question, what you meant is if you click delete on 1 or multiple items and scroll, the progress bar takes random positions?

Comment: @Gautam forget about crash. you're right for second case. it swaps the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your problem you can take the below approach.

1) Inside your `Event`pojo/model class, declare a boolean `isSelected`which will be initially false. Now whenever user clicks the row, do `

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
eventList.get(position).isSelected=true;
delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

So by doing this, we are keeping in memory which object is selected and which is not, but once you recycle your views bindViewHolder will be invoked aagain and UI elements setter will be called again so put a check inside `onBindViewHolder()`

```
if(eventList.get(position).isSelected){
    //show progress bar
}else{
   // show delete icon
}
```

To remove the item, just do the following changes in your adapter-

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    eventList.remove(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Comment: This I fixed via some different way. But I told you no the position swap problem, that is not solved

Comment: See: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ePOfZctEO_IhzUM3bFYW3VJKThoVkI6a

Comment: @ShefaliSingh why you want to do this if you are anyhow going to remove the item? why do you want to change the visibility? since the item is anyhow going to be removed. Just remove the object from the list i.e list.removeAt(position) & do adapter.notifyitemremoved(position)

Comment: I'm not that much bother about that. The main thing is while it's deleting and progressbar running, if I'm scrolling the recyclerview, that running progressbar is swaping into some random position

Comment: That's what, since you are going to remove just do two operations as mentioned above. Now regarding its swapping the position is only because of views being recycled and you might not be strong the boolean as suggested above. Have you made the changes as suggested above? Also is your item getting removed from list or not?

Comment: Okay, let me do this also

Comment: Sure, also do check if the correct item is getting removed or not from the list. This will help you in debugging the issue furthermore

Comment: I tried, but the same problem persists .Check updated code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ePOfZctEO_IhzUM3bFYW3VJKThoVkI6a

Comment: correct items is being removed, that was working previously also, but while scrolling progressbar swaps pos randomly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214056/discussion-between-gautam-and-shefali-singh).